# Finding numbers that satisfy equations involving complex numbers

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

The question: "find natural numbers for k such that  :
$z1^k = z2^k = 1$

$$z1 = \frac{1}{2}(1+i\sqrt{3})$$

$$z2 = i$$

I am not sure how else I could solve this, other than using trial and error. Apparently matrices can help however I dont see how.

(If there is a better title to use please give suggestions)

Comment: try $k=6$ this is the lowest natural number

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how'd you work that out..? $i^6 = -1$ not $1$

Comment: sorry for that in this case you must take $$k=12$$

Comment: To get subscripts in MathJax, use an underline character.  So z_1 becomes $z_1$ when put between dollar signs.  For multicharacter subscripts, put braces around them, so z_{12} gives $z_{12}$